Navigation takes me to an empty page
I want my app to navigate to SearchResults when I first open it so I put the logic to change the uiState in the ViewModel init block. Then I used an if statement to check the ViewModel and navigate to SearchResults if certain conditions are met. Then when I run the code it doesn't automatically take me to the results page I have to manually click the search button.
In addition to that when I do click the search button the page is blank and only has the search composable and the top app bar (left), when I click the back button the page becomes normal (right):
 
FlightApp:
@Composable
fun FlightApp() {
    val viewModel: FlightsViewModel = viewModel(factory = FlightsViewModel.Factory)
    val uiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    val navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
    val backStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentScreen = FlightScreen.valueOf(
        backStackEntry?.destination?.route ?: FlightScreen.Home.name
    )
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            AppBar(
                onBackButtonClick = {
                    navController.navigateUp()
                    //viewModel.resetSearchState()
                },
                currentScreen = currentScreen,
                canNavigateBack = navController.previousBackStackEntry != null
            )
        }
    ) {innerPadding ->
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
            Search(
                query = uiState.value.initialQuery,
                onQueryChange = { viewModel.onQueryChange(it) },
                onSearch = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        viewModel.onSearch()
                    }
                    navController.navigate(FlightScreen.SearchResults.name)
                },
                onSuggestionClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        viewModel.getSearchResults(it)
                    }
                    navController.navigate(FlightScreen.SearchResults.name)
                },
                isActive = uiState.value.searchState == SearchState.Searching,
                airportSuggestions = uiState.value.airportSuggestions
            )
            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = FlightScreen.Home.name,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(8.dp)
            ) {
                composable(route = FlightScreen.Home.name) {
                    HomeScreen(
                        favouriteRoutes = uiState.value.favourites,
                        onFavouriteChange = { viewModel.onFavouriteChange(it) }
                    )
                }
                composable(route = FlightScreen.SearchResults.name) {
                    SearchResults(
                        routes = uiState.value.routes,
                        onFavouriteChange = { viewModel.onFavouriteChange(it) }
                    )
                }
                //if statement checks for conditions then navigates
                //edit: this was the cause of the problem and it's fixed in the answer. 

                if (uiState.value.searchState == SearchState.Searched && uiState.value.routes.isNotEmpty()) {
                    navController.navigate(FlightScreen.SearchResults.name)
                    viewModel.onSearch()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Above is the if statement I am talking about
ViewModel:
class FlightsViewModel(
    val flightRepository: FlightRepository
): ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(FlightsUiState(SearchState.NoSearch, listOf(), "", listOf(), listOf()))
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            updateFavourites()
        }
        viewModelScope.launch {
            initialSearch()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun initialSearch() {
        flightRepository.lastQuery.collect {lastQuery ->
            _uiState.update {flightsUiState ->
                flightsUiState.copy(
                    initialQuery = lastQuery
                )
            }
            if (_uiState.value.initialQuery != "") {
                onQueryChange(_uiState.value.initialQuery)
                onSearch()
            }
        }
    }

    fun onQueryChange(query: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            flightRepository.getSuggestions(query).collect { airportSuggestions ->
                _uiState.update { flightsUiState ->
                    flightsUiState.copy(
                        initialQuery = query,
                        searchState = SearchState.Searching,
                        airportSuggestions = airportSuggestions
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        viewModelScope.launch {
            flightRepository.saveLastQuery(query)
        }
    }

    fun onSearch() {
        _uiState.update {
            it.copy(
                searchState = SearchState.Searched
            )
        }
        if (_uiState.value.airportSuggestions.size == 1) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                getSearchResults(_uiState.value.airportSuggestions[0])
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun updateFavourites() {
        flightRepository.getFavourites().collect {favourites ->
            _uiState.update { flightsUiState ->
                flightsUiState.copy(
                    favourites = favourites
                )
            }
        }
    }

    fun onFavouriteChange(route: Route) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (route.isFavourite == 1) {
                flightRepository.onFavouriteChange(route.copy(isFavourite = 0))
            } else {
                flightRepository.onFavouriteChange(route.copy(isFavourite = 1))
            }
            updateFavourites()
        }
    }

    suspend fun getSearchResults(departureAirport: Airport) {
        flightRepository.getSearchResults(departureAirport).collect {routes ->
            _uiState.update {flightsUiState ->
                flightsUiState.copy(
                    searchState = SearchState.Searched,
                    routes = routes
                )
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                val application = (this[APPLICATION_KEY] as FlightApplication)
                FlightsViewModel(application.container.flightRepository)
            }
        }
    }
}

data class FlightsUiState(
    val searchState: SearchState = SearchState.NoSearch,
    val favourites: List<Route>,
    val initialQuery: String,
    val airportSuggestions: List<Airport>,
    val routes: List<Route>
)

enum class SearchState {
    NoSearch,
    Searching,
    Searched
}

SearchResults:
@Composable
fun SearchResults(
    routes: List<Route>,
    onFavouriteChange: (Route) -> Unit
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        if (routes.isNotEmpty()) {
            val departureCode = routes[0].departureCode
            Text(
                text = stringResource(R.string.flights_from, departureCode),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 16.dp)
            )
            FlightsColumn(routes = routes) { onFavouriteChange(it) }
        } else {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(R.string.no_results),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }
    }
}


I found out that the problem was with an if statement so I fixed it and editied my viewmodel a bit.
class FlightsViewModel(
    private val flightRepository: FlightRepository
): ViewModel() {

//some code

    private suspend fun initialSearch() {
        flightRepository.lastQuery.collect {lastQuery ->
            _uiState.update {flightsUiState ->
                flightsUiState.copy(
                    initialQuery = lastQuery,

                    //added this
                    doInitialSearch = true  
                )
            }
            if (_uiState.value.initialQuery != "") {
                onQueryChange(_uiState.value.initialQuery)
                onSearch()
            }
        }
    }
    //new function
    fun initialSearchDone() {              
        _uiState.update {
            it.copy(doInitialSearch = false)
        }
    }
//some code

}
data class FlightsUiState(
    val searchState: SearchState = SearchState.NoSearch,
    val favourites: List<Route>,
    val initialQuery: String,
    val airportSuggestions: List<Airport>,
    val routes: List<Route>,

    //added this variable
    var doInitialSearch: Boolean   
)

The if statement now looks like this:
if (uiState.value.doInitialSearch) {
    navController.navigate(FlightScreen.SearchResults.name)
    viewModel.initialSearchDone()
}


It seems you're updating the state to searched before you call the getsearchresults and then after again
The second update will not trigger a recomposition as nothing has changed.
If you update the state to searching and then searched when fully complete the UI will recompose

Although updating the search state to searched before calling getsearchresults is unnecessary, it's not the cause of the problem.
